# Bootstrap 3 Collapse issue regarding height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been struggling for a while with this - which I assume - small issue. I try to combine Bootstrap 3 list groups and the collapse plugin.

I had a specific version working, but after some refactoring, it doesn't seem to collapse properly anymore, although I use the same 'strategy' as I did before. I just moved the `list-group-item` class from an achor tag to its parent div-tag. The problem is that it does not 'cover' my divs (and anchors) entirely.

I was able to extract the crucial parts:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".list-things" class="list-group-item active">Things</a>
  <div class="list-group-item list-things in">
        <a href="#">Foo</a>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group-item list-things in">
        <a href="#">Bar</a>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group-item list-things in">
        <a href="#">Baz</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

An important thing to keep in mind is that the `list-group` needs to have direct 'access' to its children annotated with `list-group-item`. Otherwise, each `list-group-item` will stand on its own having a 'double' border (`border-top` and `border-bottom`) because it's the `:first` and `:last` child; which makes it behave this way if you look this up in the Bootstrap CSS.

Because a Bootply is way more handy than just reading some code, here's a link to it: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/115155). Maybe it's also useful to show what I originally had (only the crucial stuff as well): [Bootply original](http://www.bootply.com/115165)

Anyone got an idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I came up with. Though your "Bootply original" Seems to be working.

Major changes:

1. `data-target` to `href`
2. added `collapse` class to main `list-things` div
3. made seperate nested `<div class="list-group-item">`

> ```
> <div class="list-group">
>   <a data-toggle="collapse" href=".list-things" class="list-group-item active">Things</a>
>     <div class="list-things collapse in">
>       <div class="list-group-item">
>         <a href="#">Foo</a>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>     <div class="list-things collapse in">
>       <div class="list-group-item">
>         <a href="#">Bar</a>
>       </div>
>       </div>
>     <div class="list-things collapse in">
>       <div class="list-group-item">
>         <a href="#">Baz</a>
>       </div>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Well, it surely works, but it seems that I forget to mention something that I look for in the solution to this problem.

Just as your suggestion, my original code works. But if you look closely to the borders of each div, you see they're 'doubled' everytime.

This happens because the individual list-group-items don't 'see' each other. Each list-group-item in our solutions is the :first AND :last, creating two borders (top and bottom).

That's why it's important not to wrap the list-group-items in another div. I hope I explained myself clearly enough and thanks for your shot at it ;)